# Why paint is peeling from the steel

Tags: paint, repainting, steel, damage

It's been a year since the pipe is painted, But it's peeling.

I paid good money for painting this from high quality brand.

But just want to understand the factors behind the peeling so next time when it's painted , I can take steps to prevent this from happening again.

Please note that primer was applied first then it was painted.

[image]

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: Is that yellow color your primer? Or the previous top coat that you primed over? Or a previous top coat from earlier still?

Comment: @popham - Yes it's the primer.. it's a brand new steel

Comment: The paint peeled because the adhesion to its substrate has failed.   Why?  We do not know, and you haven't told us about the type of metal, What type of paint was used, the climate it is subject to,  what the beams function is, where it is located on the structure, etc.

Comment: @RMDman - I have updated the question with the one more pic i think that would answer your questions. Basically the damage is on the outside. The metal is GI.

Comment: Located outside like that, expansion and contraction under temperature changes is a likely cause. The fix would be to use an exterior paint intended to flex with the steel. Degreasing the piece before painting will also be necessary.

Comment: I asked the painter to use appropriate paint not sure if he really bought the exterior paint. He's not answering my call :( . Your suggestion let me see through what's happening. I appreciate it

Comment: Sounds like you got a hack for a painter and you didn't check references. Grind it down and use a paint designed for the substrate. I have sprayed tons of Sherwin Williams Pro Industrial DTM (direct to metal) acrylic. Solid product.

Comment: Usual failure mode is rust...

Comment: @matt. - Yes I will try and find the paint meant for the steel substrate